# Code equivalent for android:password="false"

Tags: android

I'd like to ask a simple question, what is the equivalent **android code** for **android:password="false"** on the xml layout file. (I googled it but can't find the result:) )

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent to `android:password="false"` is [`TextView.setTransformation(null)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29). Using it with [`PasswordTransformationMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html) is equivalent of `android:password="true"`

Comment: I'm assuming that he wants to override a android:password="true" set in XML.  So it would be TextView.setTransformation(null);

Comment: Doh! Of course... :-) I should read a bit more careful. Updated the answer with @slund comment.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by equivalent android code? If your `Editview` field is password field, you set `android:password="true"`, if it is not , you don't set anything

Comment: Setting `android:password="true"` assumes there is a layout file. If the UI is generated at run time based on user input or external data, that might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for that [android:password](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3apassword) attribute says to use

```
setTransformationMethod(TransformationMethod method)
```

on your TextView.  Probably easier to [use this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29):

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```